# Generic error [50000-175] caused by NullPointerException

Tags: java, h2

I am using H2 database in client-server mode. Server is running with version 1.3.175 and client with 1.3.168.

Everything seems working fine, but I get an exception executing some queries:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-175]
>       at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
>       at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:161)
>       at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:284)
>       at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:218)
>       at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.h2.expression.Function.getCost(Function.java:2391)
>       at org.h2.expression.CompareLike.getCost(CompareLike.java:417)
>       at org.h2.expression.ConditionAndOr.optimize(ConditionAndOr.java:133)
>       at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:813)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:240)
>       at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:436)
>       at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:260)
>       at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:156)
>       ... 1 more

```
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:567)
at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.prepare(CommandRemote.java:67)
at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.<init>(CommandRemote.java:46)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.prepareCommand(SessionRemote.java:439)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1109)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:74)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:264)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in this version of the database engine, which was fixed in [revision 5437 of the trunk](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/detail?r=5437).

You can either:

- go back to the [previous version (1.3.174)](http://h2database.com/html/download.html) which should not have this bug,
- use the latest [nightly build](http://h2database.com/html/build.html#automated) where it should be fixed,
- download [the latest source code](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/checkout) and built the database yourself, or
- wait for the next version of H2.