# H2 - General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-182]

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, h2

I have a quite big (>2.5 GB) h2 database file. Driver version is 1.4.182. Everything worked fine but recently the DB stop to work with exception:

```
Błąd ogólny: "java.lang.NullPointerException"
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-182] HY000/50000 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Błąd ogólny: "java.lang.NullPointerException"
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-182] 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:297) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:260) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:60) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:167) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:145) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:128) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:26) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:347) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:92) 
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:750) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.test(WebApp.java:895) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:221) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:170) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:137) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.compare(ValueDataType.java:102) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.compare(MVMap.java:741) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.Page.binarySearch(Page.java:388) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.put(MVMap.java:179) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.put(MVMap.java:133) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.rollbackTo(TransactionStore.java:491) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.rollback(TransactionStore.java:785) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.initTransactions(MVTableEngine.java:223) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:736) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:266) 
... 17 more
```

The problem occurs in my application and using H2 web frontend.
I have tried solution from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724841/generic-error-50000-175-caused-by-nullpointerexception) but I cannot downgrade H2 to 1.3.x as it cannot read 1.4.x DB files.

**My questions are**:

How to handle it? Is it to possible to make it work again? I have tried downgrade H2 to 1.4.177 but it didn't help.

Is there any way to at least recover data to other format? I could use other DB (Sqlite, etc.) however I would need a way to get to these data.

**EDIT:** updated stacktrace

**EDIT 2:** Result of using Recovery tool:

```
$ java -cp h2-1.4.182.jar org.h2.tools.Recover
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag 50 [1.4.182/6]
   at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:762)
   at org.h2.mvstore.type.ObjectDataType.read(ObjectDataType.java:222)
   at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$ArrayType.read(TransactionStore.java:1792)
   at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$ArrayType.read(TransactionStore.java:1759)
   at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:843)
   at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:230)
   at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:1813)
   at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:769)
   at org.h2.mvstore.Page.getChildPage(Page.java:252)
   at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.getFirstLast(MVMap.java:351)
   at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.firstKey(MVMap.java:218)
   at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.init(TransactionStore.java:169)
   at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.<init>(TransactionStore.java:117)
   at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.<init>(TransactionStore.java:81)
   at org.h2.tools.Recover.dumpMVStoreFile(Recover.java:593)
   at org.h2.tools.Recover.process(Recover.java:331)
   at org.h2.tools.Recover.runTool(Recover.java:192)
   at org.h2.tools.Recover.main(Recover.java:155)
```

I also noticed that two another files (.txt and .sql) has been created but they don't seem to contain  a data.

Comment: This is the stack trace for the old version (1.4.177), could you post the stack trace for the newest version (1.4.182) please?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I updated stacktrace but it seems to be the same.

Comment: Did you try using the `Recover` tool? This is in package `org.h2.tools`. See also the documentation for this tool.

Comment: I have added stacktrace after using the tool.

Comment: I'm afraid this database file is so broken it can't be repaired. I'm interested to analyze this problem. Would it be possible if you send me the database file?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to send you the data. But is there any way to recover at least a part of data?

Comment: Probably most of the data can be retrieved, but the Recover tool right now can't handle this case. I will see what I can do, but it will take some time.

Comment: I have change the Recover tool of H2 in the trunk so in theory it should continue even in this case. Would it be possible for you to test it? You would need to build H2 yourself from the trunk at https://code.google.com/p/support/source/checkout

Answer (score 15):

I got the same situation last week with JIRA database, it took me few hours to do google regarding to this problem however, there are no answers which can resolve the situation.

I decided to take a look at H2 source code and I can recover the whole database with very simple code. I may not understand whole picture about the situation e.g. root cause, in which condition it happened, etc. 
However, the cause is: when you connect to h2 file then H2 engine will look into auditLog and rollback the in-progress transactions, there are some data which have unknown type (id is 17) and H2 fails to rollback due to exception during recognize the type (id 17).

My code is simple, add h2 lib into your build path then just manual connect to file and clear auditLog because I think it is just the log and will not have big impact (someone may correct me).
Hopefully, you can resolve your problem as well.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // open the store (in-memory if fileName is null)
    final MVStore store = MVStore.open("C:\\temp\\h2db.mv.db");

    final MVMap<Object, Object> openMap = store.openMap("undoLog");

    openMap.clear();

    // close the store (this will persist changes)
    store.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me too! I've made a simple project here: https://github.com/nyg/h2-recover

Comment: That worked for me as well. Thank you very much! Cheers!

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you!! I've got a system where some users liked a pre-production demo so much they insisted on using it immediately. You saved the day with this, while the whole incident has inspired me to really get things in gear on switching to a proper production database!

Comment: The mentioned script didn't help me. Switching to 1.4.199 did the trick https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2078#issuecomment-542173798

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, still works with Jira 8.11. I made a short [groovy script](https://gist.github.com/jofrev/9b9f24c05d9fb3365622ffbe138c7769) out of this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for this problem:

1. Go to your home folder (~ in linux).
2. Move all files named [*.mv.db] to a backup with a different name.  For example:  `mv xyz.mv.db xyz.mv.db.backup`
3. Restart your database.

This seems to clear out MVStore meta-data used for H2 undo features, and resolves the NPE from the MV Store compare.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
[HY000][50000] Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.NullPointerException"
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-176]
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried to connect with IntelliJ to H2 file DB. H2 driver version was 1.3.176 but the DB file version had 1.3.161. So downgraded the driver to 1.3.161 in IntelliJ solved the problem completely.